# cannot send complete string when used escape character

Tags: java, escaping

Here is a simple implementation of TCPServer where all i wanted to do is send a string to client when requested.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPServer{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4888);
    while(true){
        Socket client = server.accept();
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        String send = "Bhushan Patil \n 11-237 \n CMPN";
        out.writeBytes(send);
        }
    }
}
```

But on clinet side only Bhushan Patil is shown not the rest of the string.

Here is the code of client.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class TCPClient{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    Socket client = new Socket("localhost",4888);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream    ()));
    String display = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(display);
}
}
```

Can anyone explain why it is happening?
When i do

```
System.out.println(send);
```

I get the whole string with \n so i am assuming that you dont get new lines. Correct me if i am wrong. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readLine` reads all the incoming input data terminated with a newline character. Therefore, you need to continuously read the input from the client in a loop.

```
while ((display = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(display);
}
```

Also make sure to close the client socket from the server to end the connection as per [Oracle's Sample Server](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/SampleServer.java)

```
client.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Update the client code as below :

```
 String  display = null  
 while ((display = in.readLine()) != null)
  {
       System.out.println(display );
  }
```

Comment: I get the output as 
Bhushan Patil
 11-237

Comment: then the client hangs. It doesnt terminate abd doesnt give the last line CMPN

Comment: restart the service may b some cpu load block the processing

Comment: so wat the output u r receiving now ??

Comment: Bhushan Patil(Enter)(space)11-237

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46849/discussion-between-niks-tyagi-and-bhushanpatil)

Answer (score 0):

Because `in.readLine()` only read first line.
your are not reading rest of line.
You need to loop throw bufferreader to read all line.
Your output in System.out.println(send) is

```
Bhushan Patil 
 11-237 
 CMPN
```

Which contain new line character that divide your string into multiple line and `.readLine()` function read only one line at a time.

You may use [.read(char[] cbuf,int off,int len)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) to read text.
For Example :

```
char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
while (in.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length) != null) {
      String str =  new String(cbuf);  
      System.out.print(str);
}
```

Comment: can you give me a snippet that i can use to test? I tried scanner but i am not able to display CMPN and my client hangs

Comment: used above code
String  display = null; 
 while ((display = in.readLine()) != null)
  {
       System.out.println(display);
  } 
  doesn't work

Comment: It displays all the three lines but my clinet doesnt stop even when i use clinet.close()

Comment: have you got any exception or it is hang ?

Comment: it is hanged no exception